# Error while inserting data in GridView - Tried changes in web.config as well

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I was following a video to add/update/delete a row from grid view at run-time. Rest all the functionalities are working fine but i'm getting an error while inserting data in the GridView.

The error is:

> 'TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The c# code for inserting data is as follows:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvDynamicTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInsertName")).Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["MobileNumber"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvDynamicTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInsertMobileNumber")).Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["City"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)gvDynamicTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtInsertCity")).Text;
SqlDataSource1.Insert();
```

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You do not have a complete example.

Comment: The error indicates `FindControl` method returns wrong object, which doesn't have `Text` property. Provide further code sample for better analysis.